# Is it possible to parse "Not secure connection" messages using curl?

Tags: curl, https

Is it possible to parse domain that resolves when you try to enter to the website using https and certificate is not signed? <= Using CURL or something else?

I mean if you enter to https://www.microsoft.com but by it's IP address https://95.100.190.72 you will get this text where I need to extract just [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com)

```
...
This server could not prove that it is 95.100.190.72; its security certificate is from www.microsoft.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

Comment: Probably better to parse the actual certificate directly.

Comment: Yeah, good idea, thank you!